# When returning nonzero from WH_MOUSE_LL mouse positions are invalid

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, hook

I want to retrieve mouse positions *and* block the normal system mouse without resorting to raw INPUT. Theoretically this is possible but it seems that when I block (return 1) with the low level mouse hook the coordinates of the mouse are also not valid anymore. Each move to a new position results in additional mouse positions (generated by the system) back to the original position. Either returning 0 or calling SetCursorPos() makes it work but that's just what I don't want. Any tips/hints on getting correct mouse positions while also blocking the mouse are appreciated!

The DLL code (ml.dll):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

#ifndef LLMHF_INJECTED
#define LLMHF_INJECTED 1
#endif

static void * self ;
static void * hook ;

__declspec(dllexport) BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE instance, DWORD reason, LPVOID reserved)
{
  if(DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH == reason)
  {
    self = instance ;

    DisableThreadLibraryCalls(instance);
  }

  return TRUE;
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK hook_mouse(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  MSLLHOOKSTRUCT * msl = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

  if(code < 0)
  {
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
  }

  switch(wParam)
  {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE   :
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN :
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN :
    case WM_MBUTTONDOWN :
    case WM_LBUTTONUP   :
    case WM_RBUTTONUP   :
    case WM_MBUTTONUP   :

    default             : break;
  }

  printf("%3d,%3d (marker : 0x%08x) : W:%u L:%u\n", msl -> pt.x, msl -> pt.y, msl -> dwExtraInfo, wParam, lParam);

  CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);

  return 1;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void mouse_hook_low_start(int marker)
{
  if(NULL == (hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, hook_mouse, self, 0)))
  {
    assert(0);
  }
}

__declspec(dllexport) void mouse_hook_low_stop(void)
{
    if(FALSE == UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook))
    {
      assert(0);
    }
}
```

The test.exe code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <windows.h>

static DWORD pid;

enum {

  TRIGGER = WM_APP + 1024,

} ;

static DWORD WINAPI hook(LPVOID param)
{
  int done = 0;

  void * dll = LoadLibrary("ml.dll");

  assert(dll);

  void (*start)(void) = (void (*)(void))GetProcAddress(dll, "mouse_hook_low_start");
  void (*stop)(void) = (void (*)(void))GetProcAddress(dll, "mouse_hook_low_stop");

  assert(start);
  assert(stop);

  start();

  while(0 == done)
  {
    MSG msg;

    while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
      if(TRIGGER == msg.message)
      {
        done = 1;

        break ;
      }

      DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    Sleep(5);
  }

  stop();
}

void start_hook(void)
{
  void * thread;

  if(NULL == (thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, hook, NULL, 0, &pid)))
  {
    assert(0);
  }
}

void stop_hook(void)
{
  if(0 == PostThreadMessage(pid, TRIGGER, 0, 0))
  {
    assert(0);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  setbuf(stdout, NULL);
  setbuf(stderr, NULL);

  SetCursorPos(100,100);

  start_hook();

  getchar();

  stop_hook();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to block mouse movement? You could just use [`ClipCursor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383.aspx) for that instead of a low-level hook.

Comment: @Remy I want to retrieve mouse positions, ClipCursor just restrict the bounding rectangle, so that is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: you say you want to block the mouse. Block what exactly? Block the mouse from moving? Block apps from receiving mouse movement events? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, I want to block the system from receiving mouse events but still 'steal' those events. So get the mouse coordinates and then block further processing of those events. At the same time this is happening I want to inject different events (so different mouse coordinates) into the system. The latter will wind up in the mouse hook again but I can detect that and pass them through. The idea is that a virtual user from over the network can move the mouse while I can also show where the hardware mouse is by getting those events.

Comment: Instead of manipulating the hardware mouse, I would suggest displaying your own "virtual" mouse instead (just create a free-floating window that has an image of a mouse cursor, and then move it around as needed), and hide the hardware mouse cursor if desired. Let the remote user move the virtual mouse around and send fake mouse events where needed, but let the local user move the hardware mouse around normally.  No hooks needed.

Comment: That's the idea :) But for that to work I will still need to block the hardware cursor otherwise if he moves the mouse while the virtual user is dragging/moving it will screw up those coordinates. And for the guy at the computer to have the idea that he is moving his mouse I would need to not only block it, but also get those coordinates so I can move his virtual mouse (while the remote user would be doing actual stuff with the system cursor). This should all work in theory but alas the thing that is not working is the fact that windows seems to return invalid coords once the hook returns 1.

Comment: I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. The hardware mouse and the virtual mouse would be managed independently of each other. When a user moves his hardware mouse, those coordinates are sent to the other person so the virtual mouse can be moved around on that end. When a user clicks his hardware mouse, that into is sent to the other person so fake input messages can be issued on that end. This allows both mouses to be visible at the same time, and allows both users to interact with the UI at the same time, but without clashing with each other.

Comment: Let the OS handle the local hardware mouse normally, do not block it. You only need to manage the virtual mouse yourself.

Comment: If I do not block the hardware mouse the following would happen: the virtual user is moving his mouse (so I am injecting/doing setcursorpos()) and drawing a fake cursor - so far so good. But now the other guy moves his cursor, and then the setcursor will interfere with the actual cursor position. So I need to block the hardware cursor once the virtual guy is moving the mouse. Now, since I still want to show the mouse position of the local guy I want to get the coordinates of his mouse, so I am blocking him but still need to show *his* virtual mouse at this point. Hope I am making sense :)

Comment: DON'T call `SetCursorPos()` in that case. `SetCursorPos()` moves the local user's hardware mouse, which you should not do in response to the remote user's activity. You should move the local user's virtual mouse instead. I don't think you are fully understanding the separation that I have outlined. You are trying to have both users manipulate the local user's hardware mouse, and I'm saying DON'T do that. If you want to show the local user's mouse position on the local PC, let the OS show the actual mouse cursor normally. The remote user moves the local virtual mouse, not the real mouse.

Comment: Only one user can control the hardware at one single time, I understand. The virtual user can move his fake mouse cursor too, and in fact can control the hardware by just doing SendInput(). You have to block the hardware mouse though to allow this. And that also works but when you do that you can no longer show the virtual mouse for the local guy. And that's where the problem is - so showing the fake mouse for the remote guy is not the problem, but you sometimes want to let that guy have control and when you do you can no longer have the local guy touch his mouse or that would screw up.

Comment: Basically the users have to switch, when the local guy is in control then there is no problem. The remote guy can just move his fake mouse around but do nothing. When the remote guy wants control then I switch cursors, the remote guy gets the real mouse cursor and can do stuff - that works fine by just doing SetCursorPos() and/or SendInput(). But now the local guy moves his mouse - you have to block that otherwise it will screw up the mouse coords of the remote guy. Blocking is possible, but you also still want to give the local guy *his* fake cursor - so you still need his coords...

Comment: [`BlockInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290.aspx) can be used to start/stop hardware blocking without resorting to a hook. If that does not block the [Raw Input API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) from delivering input to your app, then there is your solution.

Comment: I know I can use Raw input, but I wanted to find a solution without resorting to raw input (see my original question). I would not need raw input if the coordinates in the mouse hook weren't corrupted but alas they are. Thanks so much for all the feedback and thinking along with me! But I think this is unsolvable :) Thanks again, Remy!

Comment: What's wrong with using Raw Input? For mouse/keyboard input, it is quite straight forward. Its HID devices (joysticks, game controllers, etc) that are more complex.